# Is it possible to use Angular async pipe with FullCalendar?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5, async-pipe

If it is possible, does anyone have an example of how to use async pipe in FullCalendar? For example something like this?

```
<full-calendar [events]="events$ | async"></full-calendar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a container around your html tag and pass the entire config options object:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="calendarOptions2$ | async as options">
  <full-calendar [options]="options"></full-calendar>
</ng-container>
```

Working example:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ht8hof

Answer (score 1):

using the `async` pipe this way will actually work.
But the problem is that `full-calendar` is not expected any input named `events`

The only input it expect is `options`

so your code should like:

```html
<full-calendar [options]="{
        events: events$ | async
    }"></full-calendar>
```

Comment: This should work, but it "hijack" the options attribute, wouldn't it.